# Rails Model Associations Mutex / Locking?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, models, model-associations

I've read quite a bit about pessimistic and optimistic locking on models in rails.  However, I've yet to find any sort of information on how to implement locking on a ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy ..

For instance,

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :model_other_models
  has_many :other_models, :through => :model_other_models

  def do_stuff
    self.with_lock do
      # do other stuff
      new_model = OtherModel.new ( ... )
      other_models << new_model
    end
  end

  def modify_other_models
    self.other_models.each do |other_model|
      other_model.with_lock do
        # other stuff
      end
    end
  end

end
```

This seems all fine and dandy, but what if in another instance of my multi-threaded application server a user is accessing the model's "other_models" association at the same time one is being added to it in this situation here.  Would that not cause a race condition?

Would a class level mutex on the other_models association collection solve this problem?  Must I lock the entire table that joins the model to other_models?  How can I accomplish this?  Is this a job for optimistic locking implemented on the model_other_models association?

I've found much information on how to actually lock records of models themselves, but nothing about a collection of models as part of model assocations.

Thank you.

### Update

I believe that the answer was right in front of me.  There is no way to stop other classes from going around your model's methods and directly accessing the associations, but if proper practice is used, then it solves this issue.

If one instance is in the process of adding a record B to the association collection proxy and is using the record lock for record A, but another instance is directly accessing record A's collection of record B's without the lock, then a race condition is present.

If an add and remove method of the model modify the association collection proxy, but both use the lock associated with the record, the race condition is eliminated.

The downside here is that any operation involving a record's associations must rely on locking the entire record itself, which may be very unnecessary depending on the situation.  It would be ideal it were possible to lock ONLY the association collection.